# EF cascade delete on single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, cascade

I have a `Category` class

```
public class Category : BaseEntity {
    //[Key]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    //public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public int? PId { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("PId")]
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

A category may have a `Parent` category with optional and have many sub categories, just like a tree.

When deleting a category, I want to delete sub categories in a cascade. I have tried below code:

```
 public CategoryMapping() {
        HasKey(t => t.Oid);
        Property(t => t.Oid).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(t => t.CreatedDate).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Uid).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();

        ToTable("W_CATEGORY");

        this.HasMany(wi => wi.Subcategories).WithOptional(wi => wi.Parent).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

It does not work properly. can anyone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server won't allow you to setup a cascade delete on a self-referencing relationship, There is a potential of cyclical logic problems. This way you can delete a category with its children:

```
public void Remove(int id)
{
    var selectedCategory = _category.Find(id);
    _category.Where(x => x.ParentId == id).Load();
    _category.Remove(selectedCategory);
}
```

Or you can use this way:

```
private Stack<Category> GetChildsAndRoot(Category category)
{
            var stack = new Stack<Category>();
            var queue = new Queue<Category>();
            stack.Push(category);
            queue.Enqueue(category);
            while (queue.Any())
            {
                var currCategory = queue.Dequeue();
                foreach (var child in currCategory.Childs)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(child);
                    stack.Push(child);
                }
            }

            return stack;
}
var category = _categoryRepository.GetByID(id);

var nodes = GetChildsAndRoot(category);
while (nodes.Any())
{
        _categoryRepository.Delete(nodes.Pop());
}

_unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```